# How can I paginate Docker commands?

Tags: shell, docker, less

The output of some Docker commands (such as `docker container ls`) takes a lot of space of my terminal, causing a lot of line breaks, which makes the reading to be a frustrating task.

So I wondered if I can use some kind of *pager tool* (such as `less`, which I use in `psql`) to paginate the output of all Docker commands.

Apparently, `psql` accepts an environment variable `PAGER` to define it. I've tried to do the same with `docker`, but sadly did not succeed:

```
# How I do in `psql`:
PAGER="less -S" psql

# This does not work:
PAGER="less -S" docker container ls
```

- **How can I paginate Docker commands?**

Comment: What you can do is a specify a `--format` string to get only the information you want.